# The version of this file is not compatible with the version of windows

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I wrote a program in python 3.6.2 in windows10,i convert it to .exe file by Cx_Freeze.i wrote bellow code to convert it:
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

```
import os
import sys
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\seyed_vahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\seyed_vahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\tcl\tk8.6'
packages = ['idna','queue.py']
include_files=[r'C:\Users\seyed_vahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs\tcl86t.dll',r'C:\Users\seyed_vahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs\tk86t.dll',r'C:\Users\seyed_vahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\sticker.png',r'C:\Users\seyed_vahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\about.png',r'C:\Users\seyed_vahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\emoji1.png',r'C:\Users\seyed_vahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\telegram.png']
base = None
if (sys.platform == "win32"):
    base = "Win32GUI"
setup(name = "MegaGram",
    version = "1.0.0",
    description = "MegaGram",
    options = {'build_exe': {'packages':packages,
        'include_files':include_files}},
    executables = [Executable("MegaGram.py",base=base,icon = 'icon.ico',)],
)
```

but when run exe file in windows 7(32bit),i get bellow error:

```
The version of this file is not compatible with the version of windows you are running cheak your computers system information to whethers you need an x86 or x64 version of the program,and then 
contact the software publisher.
```

how fix it?

Comment: Is your Python version 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: @Michael Butscher it is 64 bit.

Answer (score 2):

cx_freeze packs Python and binary modules into the final program so it becomes a 64 bit exe which can't run under a 32 bit OS.

Install a 32 bit Python and use that with cx_freeze to create a working program.